# the requestPermissions() does not respond , nothing happen when I click the button

Tags: android

Here is my code , I write like the doc said.
However nothing happen when I click the button.
There is only on massage show :"D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10155; state: ENABLED"

```
Button bt_show_contacts_list=findViewById(R.id.button_show_contacts_list);
        bt_show_contacts_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // You can use the API that requires the permission
                    start();
                }else if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"it's important , you are suppose to allow the permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},1);
                }
            }
        });

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        //Application specific request code to match with a result reported to TODO

        switch (requestCode){
            case 1:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    start();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"go to setting , otherwise you can't use this",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
        }

    }
    public void start(){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you set the click listener for the button?

Comment: I have edit the question , I thought the listener is ok.

Comment: If you pressed "Don't show again" when denying the permission in the app, it will not show the dialog again even if you call requestPermission.
Try also enabling the app permission in settings and see if the toast appears. Then try disabling it and see if the request dialog appears. That will help you pinpoint which part of the code is the problem.

Comment: I did write the     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/> in my code.After doing that , my app is going fine.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this code in AndroidManifest.xml,then the code will wordk.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```